# Покритикуйте пожалуйста мою верстку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

http://websterjoy.tk/

Хотелось бы услышать критики и замечания о верстке. Что в моем коде плохо, что можно было бы сделать лучше?

Comment: @websterjoy: Как-то с Вами можно связаться? Skype, ICQ? Есть несколько вопросов.

Comment: Skype - wwwebsterjoy, пишите

Comment: Инспекция кода (как и размещение вопросов) подразумевает, что код пишется в вопросе. С момента задания вопроса прошло 4 года - сайт наверняка поменялся и вопрос бессмысленнен.

Answer (score 4):

1. зачем ты на li вешаешь классы parent и parent-2 ?? Они там совершенно не нужны. Лучше обращайся к li .main-nav li и давай все свойства что нужно. Так же и в случае с .top-nav li
2. Все скрипты помести в один $(document).ready, а то сейчас у тебя все там разбросано
3. тегу aside вместо padding-left поставь margin-left

Answer (score 2):

1. Перенеси скрипты вниз страницы или используй атрибут defer у скриптов.
2. Структура html перегружена тегом div с самого начала. Смысла тут использовать новые html5 теги я не вижу.
3. На странице ошибка:

   TypeError: $(...).swipe is not a function
   threshold:0